Mount in a directory I don't have permissions to for my user only
Is it possible to circumvent the traditional mount permission requirements if I just need my own user to see the mount?
For example, I want to bind mount /home/$USER/folder into /folder. I do not have root permissions and thus can't just mount --bind [...]. The /folder does not exist. I do not care that any other user won't see the folder. In fact, I would be fine with only the children of one process would see this folder.

" I do not have root permissions" - No. You cannot do this without root.
